# pandas The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series of prices in a dataframe. I am trying to calculate the payoff and store it in a column in the same dataframe. However the payoff will depend on whether the share price is larger than the strike price.

I am trying the following code

```
payoff = max(df_payoff.index - row['Excercise Price'], 0)
df_payoff[row['Security']] = row['Unit Holding'] * payoff - row['Total Cost']
```

the share prices i generated using numpy and assigned it to the index of df_payoff

```
dataframe prices = np.arange(min_price, max_price, 0.01)
df_payoff = pd.DataFrame(index=prices)
```

but i get the error message in the subject. Can I do this calc in a vectorized way or do i need to iterate through each price in the dataframe?

Comment: Could you also post a sample of both tables?

Comment: edited original post.